# How to spread/hash multiple files on disk without storing more than 1000 per directory?

Tags: java, performance, hash

I need to generate a large number of files indexed by an integer. For example, assuming int i ranges from 0 to 10000, the generated files would be: f0.xml, f1.xml, ... f10000.xml

However the file system performance starts to degrade for more than 1000 files per folder.

I wanted to store the files in directories using a 'hash' or 'spread' function over the value of i. This function would store no more than 1000 files (or folders) in a single directory but would only create directories as needed.

Any ideas or open-source solutions for my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: If you pad the numbers all to five digits so you have 00000 to 99999, you can just put a slash after the first two characters, so you have 00/000 to 99/999. To create the directories as needed, create the directory if a file creation operation fails and then retry it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I implemented using some of the provided tips.
First a function to decompose the index in an array of 3 digit sets:

```
private static void decompose(final long l, final short[] array) {
    long q = l;
    long r = 0;
    for (int j=array.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        // compute remainder
        r = q % 1000;
        // compute quotient
        // converts to int and fractional part is dropped without rounding
        q = q / 1000;

        array[j] = (short) r;
    }
}
```

Then, using the decomposed array (currentA), create the subdirectories and file objects.

```
    File dir = parent;
    for (int j=0; j < depth-1; j++) {
        String dirName = String.format("%03d", currentA[j]);
        dir = new File(dir, dirName);
    }
    String fileName = prefix + String.format("%03d", currentA[depth]) + suffix;
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you generate files names by number from 00000000 to 99999999. You can use the last 3 digits as the file name i.e. your directories look like 00000/000.xml to 99999/999.xml

Note: Unless you have an SSD, your performance will degrade if you have lots of files on any file system. The typical file access time is around 8 ms on a HDD.

Comment: Thanks, but his way you would have a directory with more than 1000 subdirectories...

Comment: @MiguelPardal: so put some effort into solving your own problem, instead of putting `00000000.xml` into `00000/000.xml` try `00/000/000.xml` or whatever fits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

See this excellent post for a simple solution:

http://michaelandrews.typepad.com/the_technical_times/2009/10/creating-a-hashed-directory-structure.html

```
import java.io.File;

public class DirectoryHash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "cat.gif";

        int hashcode = fileName.hashCode();
        int mask = 255;
        int firstDir = hashcode & mask;
        int secondDir = (hashcode >> 8) & mask;

        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(File.separator);
        path.append(String.format("%03d", firstDir));
        path.append(File.separator);
        path.append(String.format("%03d", secondDir));
        path.append(File.separator);
        path.append(fileName);

        System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the name of the file, MD5 it giving you something like `abdefghijklmnop`

Break this into a directory structure and a file name e.g.

```
abc \ def \ ghi \ jkl \ mnop.txt
```

You can choose how to break the directories up based on how many files you are going to store (e.g. you might only need 8 characters split into 3,3,2 rather than a depth of 3,3,3,3 as in the example above).

Comment: Thanks, but MD5 may have collisions... I know it's unlikely but it could happen silently...

Comment: The choice of MD5 is arbitrary.  I probably should have explained it as pick as consistent naming scheme and then break it down into directories.